# templated template parameter list with template types

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

C++ allows templated template parameters like this:

```
template <template <bool> class T>
struct something1 {};
```

**Bool** type can be replaced by a **typedef** (so there is no requirement for the original type name to appear in the declaration):

```
typedef bool bool_t;
template <template <bool_t> class T>
struct something2 {};
```

This works perfectly, but if I try to define a nested **structure** like this:

```
template <typename Type>
struct enclosing
{
   typedef bool bool_t;
   typedef Type type_t; 

   template <template <bool_t> class T>
   struct something3 {};

   template <template <type_t> class T>
   struct something4 {};
};
```

Then the following code fails to compile:

```
template <bool Value>
struct param {};

typedef something1<param> x1; // ok
typedef something2<param> x2; // ok
typedef enclosing<bool>::something3<param> x3; // ok
typedef enclosing<bool>::something4<param> x4; // error
```

Is this a standard compliant behavior, or am I doing something wrong? I am using MSVS 2008.

**EDIT:**
I've posted a bug report on Microsoft support forums:
[Bug Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655445/c-compiler-bug-cannot-use-template-parameters-inside-nested-template-declaration)

Comment: For what it's worth, Comeau compiles it with no problem. Your code seems fine to me, I think it's a VC++ bug.

Comment: The code looks well-formed. VC does struggle with template template params in certain contexts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in VC++; I verified that the behavior is unchanged in VC++ 2010 SP1. I recommend posting a bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) then posting the link here so we can vote it up.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate:-(, I'll post a bug report and hope they will fix the problem in some future release. Thanks for your answer.